# Class member or instance attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ctypes

I've been using Structure in ctypes recently, but i got a strange question.

This is my Python3 code:

```
from ctypes import *
class AcknowledgeHeader(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('test', c_uint8),
    ]
ack_header = AcknowledgeHeader()
```

The question is: Is `test` a class member of AcknowledgeHeader or an instance attribute of ack_header?

I tried to find the answer.

If `test` is an instance attribute of ack_header, then why does `ack_header.__dict__` print a empty dict?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ack_header = AcknowledgeHeader()
    print(ack_header.__dict__)

C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\gige-lib\venv\Scripts\python.exe
C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/gige-lib/channel/common.py
{}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If `test` is a class member of AcknowledgeHeader, then why is `type(ack_header.test)` not equal to `type(AcknowledgeHeader.test)`?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ack_header = AcknowledgeHeader()
    print(type(ack_header.test))
    print(type(AcknowledgeHeader.test))

C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\gige-lib\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/gige-lib/channel/common.py
<class 'int'>
<class '_ctypes.CField'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test` is a **data descriptor object** on the `AcknowledgeHeader` class. Accessing it on the `ack_header` instance causes code to run that translates between C conventions and Python types.

Because it is a data descriptor, all interaction with the attribute is captured, including deletion and assignment. If you were to set a `'test'` key in the `ack_header.__dict__` attribute dictionary it'd simply be ignored.

Instead, `ack_header.test` will always invoke `AcknowledgeHeader.test.__get__(ack_header, AcknowledgeHeader)`, while assignment to `ack_header.test` will trigger `AcknowledgeHeader.test.__set__(ack_header, <new value>)`.

In this case, only getting and setting is implemented, there is no [`_ctypes.CField.__delete__()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delete__), only `__get__` and `__set__`, so `del ack_header.test` will throw an exception.

See the [descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) for more details on how descriptors work.